# i'm trying to make a php code that return the result of graph.facebook.com/facebook_page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to to make a php code that return the ID of the page when I do `graph.facebook.com/facebook_page`

For example I have a `my_file.txt` file that contain the facebook pages that I want to get the code of them.

I know the code of looping inside `my_file.txt`

```
<?php

$lines = file('my_file.txt');

foreach ($lines as $line)
{
    echo htmlspecialchars($line) . '<br>';
}

?>
```

but I can't find a way to return the ID of each page in the txt file.

Comment: Well, for starters, what are the actual contents of `my_file.txt`?

Comment: it contains the facebook pages that i want to get the code of each one of them for example: https://www.facebook.com/AnnaKareninanovel \n https://www.facebook.com/EverydayeBook \n https://www.facebook.com/BooksForBetterLiving

Comment: OK, so fetch https://graph.facebook.com/AnnaKareninanovel and parse the ID out.

Comment: how can i fetch it using foreach loop?

Comment: We're not going to write your code for you. Look at `preg_match`.